# Outook Attach .docx--Insert As Text

Tags: python, email, outlook, attachment

I am trying to send an email with an attachment as the body of the email. I want to replicate the attach-->insert as text option that you can use in the actual Outlook application.

This is the code I have tried, but it does not work to insert my document as text in the body of the email.

```
import win32com.client

#some constants (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219371%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
olFormatHTML = 2
olFormatPlain = 1
olFormatRichText = 3
olFormatUnspecified = 0
olMailItem = 0x0

obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

attachment1 = "test.docx"

with open(attachment1 , 'r') as myfile:
    data=(myfile.read())

newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"
newMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML    #or olFormatRichText or olFormatPlain
newMail.HTMLBody = data
newMail.To = "help@example.com"


newMail.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment1)

# open up in a new window and allow review before send
newMail.Display()
```